# Is it possible to create a new type of context with Python?

Tags: python, customization

I want to create a new context-panel such as these:

[image]

Is this possible with Python? My own context-panel with my own custom panels inside it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answer is actually very simple: no. :)

Afaik this is not even in our TODOs - we rather aim at creating custom spaces from py… But no ETA on that either.